# Xamarin.Forms HTTP Post to Web Service - 404 Error

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

Sorry if this question has been asked already but I can not seem to find one that relates to my issue. I have a web service built using C# Asp.Net Web API, here I have the following POST method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("AddLocation")]
    public void PostLocation(Locations model)
    {
        using (Entities db = new Entities())
        {
            C_btblFALocation newLocation = new C_btblFALocation()
            {
                cLocationCode = model.Code,
                cLocationDesc = model.Description
            };

            db.C_btblFALocation.Add(newLocation);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

In my Xamarin.Forms project I have my Rest Service Class:

```
    public async Task SaveLocationAsync(Locations item)
    {
        var uri = new Uri(string.Format(Constants.LocationSaveRestUrl));

        try
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(@"             Location successfully added.");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(@"             Oops, there seems to be a problem.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(@"             ERROR {0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

And my URL is set in my Constants class:

```
public static string LocationSaveRestUrl = "http://172.16.124.18/ArceusService/api/Assets/AddLocation/";
```

The problem is I keep getting a 404 error. I have tried every way I can think of to set the URL but no luck. The data seems to be passed through fine from debugging but I don't know how the URL should be for a POST method?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: 172.x.x.x is a private ip address is this the real issue here?

Comment: a 404 means that it is actually getting a response from the server, not a timeout

Comment: Check your controller path. Does it include Assets? Do you have AssetsController? Can you put another PC on the same network (or use your development PC) and try to issue that command using PostMan or Fiddler using EXACTLY the same URI. Does this work?

Answer (score 0):

How is your `client` variable declared? Usually you set a `BaseAddress` and in your `Get/PostAsync` you only set the actual resource URI.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://something.com/api/");
    var response = await client.GetAsync("resource/7");
}
```

Comment: Its a global variable - HttpClient client;